# How to remove jenkins user via groovy or client API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I want to delete the jenkins users via terminal.

Comment: The title of your question seems containing more more information than your question "body". Could you, please, add any detail?

Answer (score 0):

sample groovy script which would help you.

```
import hudson.model.User
User u = User.get(id)
u.delete()
```

"id" should be user user full name or his id in jenkins
http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/User.html#get(java.lang.String)
http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/User.html#delete()

Also your security strategy plays huge role in this. for more check model.securityRealm class